Supernatural film about friends who gain certain powers
I'm not all that sure on this one. But here's all that I can remember.
It's a film about three/four high school friends, one I think may be called Caleb and another one, Pheobe. I may be wrong on those.
The four friends gain powers from some meteor/giant glowing rock. One has the power too heal, one has telekinetic powers, and I'm not sure on what powers the last one has.
One of the friends, a girl with long brown hair, thinks she's amazing and decides to use her powers for evil (duh duh duhhh) and controls people at the high school, and the remaining friends go there and they have a bit of a showdown, with Pheobe nearly being killed.
This film has been on my mind for a few years on and off and I've tried searching but nobody knows what in on about. Starting to think I dreamt it up...

I'm gonna have to wait until I get home before I can check, but this sounds a lot like Chronicle.

Chronicle kept coming up whilst I was doing google searches earlier on, but I'm sure it's not that...

Interesting... I'll have a look anyway when I get home and see if I can turn up any results.

Welcome to Movies & TV! We have a minimum standard for ID questions. Please try to add anything that may help identification. When was it released? Was it in Color or Black & White? What time period was it showing? What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember?  Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. For help writing a good identification question, see: Identify-This-X Questions.

@Mr. Kenneth Jones I'm certain I watched this movie but I can't remember the name. It was an awfully made B movie with a lot of scenes in a forest.

You're looking for The Source 2002, aka "The Surge"

Four outcast teenagers acquire mystical powers that allow them to become gods on campus, with deadly consequences.



The film opens by following a moody goth named Reese, who befriends three other outcasts like him: Zack, a rich nerd; Ashley, Zack's sister; and Phoebe, a flower child. They go to a forest and find a glowing rock. They gain powers from just stepping into its presence, and they use these powers to intimidate and humiliate people who have made fun of them over the years.
Zack gains telepathy.
Phoebe gains telekinesis/psychokinesis.
Ashley gains speech-induced psychic suggestion.
Reese gains the ability to heal or hurt others/himself using his mind.
However, her power goes to Ashley's head; and she begins to take over the school, using mind control. She attacks her brother Zack and tries to kill Phoebe and Reese. They force her to heal Zack, but she forces Phoebe to levitate off the building and drop to the ground. Reese (because of his ability to heal or hurt) takes his own hearing away, when Ashley tries to control him; and he breaks the piece of the rock she had around her neck. He heals Phoebe; but, when they return to destroy the glowing rock, it has disappeared. Ashley is committed to a mental institution; but a former teacher brings her more of the glowing rock. The movie ends with her eyes turning blue, indicating that her powers have returned.

https://www.videodetective.com/movies/the-surge/667639

Hey guys! Sorry for the late reply, I forgot my password :D Thank you so much for the help! I really appreciate it :) Just looking at that picture, I know it's the film I was looking for. Thanks again :)

No problem, glad I could help (really, I love it when I know some obscure or a hard to find movie someone is looking for!). You can also mark the answer as correct by clicking on the check mark beside it.

Thank you again. I would never have been able to find it. I think I tried nearly every google search possible...
